# Merge [pixel-shader], [pixel-shading] into [fragment-shader]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

"Pixel shaders" are also known as "fragment shaders," but there is a [pixel-shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel-shader) tag, a [pixel-shading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel-shading) and a [fragment-shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fragment-shader) tag. Should these tags be merged?

Note: "pixel shader" is more commonly used in DirectX, whereas "fragment shader" is more commonly used in OpenGL and Vulkan. Yet they mean pretty much the same thing, and will usually be accompanied with a tag indicating which API the OP is using. In many questions it may not truly matter though. Some questions are already tagged with two of these tags.

Comment: Are they known *universally* by both terms? Or are there language/library/framework-specific differences? I'm assuming from your proposal that you are a topic expert; can you perhaps elaborate to provide some further justification in hopes of convincing those of us who aren't?

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not quite a GLSL expert, but I understand that "pixel shader" is an alternative name for "fragment shader." [This book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/Y-KEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA43&dq=%22pixel+shader%22+%22fragment+shader%22) defines them as synonyms, for example.

Comment: The OpenGL spec (and OpenGL ES/WebGL spec) calls the shader only "fragment shader". It never mentions the term "pixel shader". Afaik, Vulkan and Metal also use fragment shader. The only API I know which calls it pixel shader is DirectX.

Comment: Is any of these tags useful outside the specific specs? Isn't enough to have users tag with the spec and be done with it?

Comment: @Braiam: I don't think any of these tags is useful. Removing all of them would be fine for me. But merging them sounds like a bad idea,.